# Copy data from excel to kendo ui grid

Tags: user-interface, grid, kendo-ui

Is there any provision in Kendo UI web grid (MVC) to copy data from Excel?
Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks & Regards,
Chakravarti.B.

Comment: Do you mean copy data from Excel to Kendo UI Grid?!!! Please ask your question clearly.

Comment: I realize this is way too late to help you but it may help others.  The javascript was was outlined here:  https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/copy-from-excel-to-grid  and there's a working example here:  http://dojo.telerik.com/Acub  .  I haven't finished reverse engineering an example to apply it in the MVC grid format, but once I have I will post a solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Use OpenXML SDK to read data from file in xls-format on server side and populate your kendo grid with this data